# Extract point cloud data from shapefile with Python

Tags: python, shapefile, numpy, las

I am trying to plot profiles from LAS data. So my first step is to extract the data using a shapefile. I found this piece of code on the [laspy website](https://laspy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tut_part_1.html) and thought I could use it to do this :

```
def explode(coords):
   for e in coords:
       if isinstance(e, (int, float,complex)):
           yield coords
           break
       else:
           for f in explode(e):
               yield f

def bbox(f):
    x, y = zip(*list(explode(f['geometry']['coordinates'])))
    return min(x), min(y), max(x), max(y)

def clip_extract(las_file , shp_file ):
    import laspy, os
    import numpy as np

    inFile = laspy.file.File(las_file, mode = "r")
    shp = fiona.open(shp_file, "r")

    min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y = acav.bbox(shp)
    X_invalid = np.logical_and((min_x <= inFile.x),
                              (max_x >= inFile.x))
    Y_invalid = np.logical_and((min_y <= inFile.y),
                              (max_y >= inFile.y))
    Z_invalid = np.logical_and((inFile.header.min[2] <= inFile.z),
                              (inFile.header.max[2] >= inFile.z))

    good_indices = np.where(np.logical_and(X_invalid, Y_invalid, Z_invalid))
    good_points = inFile.points[good_indices]
```

But of course it extracts the full min(x), min(y), max(x), max(y) rectangle while ideally it would only extract the points within the shapefile :
[image: Points selected vs shapefile]

I have read many other posts on how to mask a numpy array with a shapefile but I can't seem to find one that match my case... I am trying to do this with Fiona or shapely, and Numpy.

Comment: it extracts all points because min, max are the bounding box of the polygon.

Comment: Hi, did you ever get a solution for this problem? @User18981898198119

Answer (score 0):

you should look at pdal.

https://pdal.io/en/latest/stages/filters.crop.html

```
import pdal
polygon_draw_bounds = polygon_draw.bounds
cropper = {
    "pipeline": [str(datasource/file),
        {   "type":"filters.crop",
            'bounds':str(([polygon_draw_bounds[0], polygon_draw_bounds[2]],[polygon_draw_bounds[1], polygon_draw_bounds[3]]))},
        {   "type":"filters.crop",
            'polygon':polygon_draw.wkt
        },
        {   "type":"writers.las",
            "filename": str(output)+"\\"+"cloud_crop.laz"
        },
    ]}
pipeline = pdal.Pipeline(json.dumps(cropper))
pipeline.execute()
```